# How to redirecting without changing URL (completely, not just one page)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm getting up a new server and migrated everything. Now the problem is I have to think a new way of redirecting "planted content".

So I am running on Linux Apache server and trying to redirect everything from **https://www.myweb.com** into **https://www.myweb.ru**. Since it is not my system and not my solution of changing language on this website I have to stick to this solution of programmer before me.

Now it should be working like this:

When you type in URL

**https://www.myweb.com/contacts**

it should redirect your content, not change your URL into

**https://www.myweb.ru/contacts**

Right now at this moment I was trying to do something like this with

> RewriteEngine on

But it is not working, it's still telling me that I have no permission to access the / directory on original website not the one I am trying to secretely redirect to.

This is the non-working magic

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^myweb.com/$(.*) https://www.myweb.ru/$1
```

//Edited: Everything is running on the very same server, it is just separated so the websites can't see each other in folders.

Also tried this and it is still returning the very same error

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^myweb.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.myweb.ru/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Do you get the error on just `/` of your original domain or on all URLs?

Comment: on all URLs it says "that" exact URL does not exist on original domain, which is true, there is only .htaccess, all languages are on one domain where I need the redirection (without changing URL), it is just so badly made this web system. So it says that URL you type in does not exist for example / on index or /contacts on contacts.

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: There are no other rules. I sucesfully redirected WITH change of URL before tho when I was trying other solutions so the .htaccess is working.

Comment: Are those both domains (hosts) actually served by the same system? Or are those separate systems?

Comment: It is on the same machine, separated virtually. I can even set different versions of PHP for each domain, they have separated .htaccess and the websites itself has some custom made CMS or what is it but it's horrible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?myweb.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.myweb.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but this rewrite URL. I am looking for solution without changing URL :)

Comment: I've actually edited a little your code. It somehow working without the R=301 and L parameters... looks like some black magic to me honestly but thank you very much!!!